# Enter a node in middle to make a sorted linked lists

Tags: c, singly-linked-list, sortedlist

Following is the program that I have tried to make it myself.I want to enter a node in the middle in such a way that a sorted link list comes as a output.But its not working.So kindly help me to get a perfect output.And make me understand what's going wrong in this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct node_type
{
    int roll_no;
    char name[10];
    float marks;
    struct node_type *next;
} node;
typedef node *list;
void show_list (list);
main () 
{
    list head, temp, tail;
    char ch;
    int n;
    head = NULL;
    printf ("Do you want to add?(y/n)");
    scanf ("%c", &ch);
    if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
    {
        tail = (list) malloc (sizeof (node));
        printf ("Enter the value for roll number:-\n");
        scanf ("%d", &(tail->roll_no));
        printf ("Enter name:-\n");
        scanf ("%s", tail->name);
        printf ("Enter marks:-\n");
        scanf ("%f", &(tail->marks));
        tail->next = head;
        head = tail;
        printf ("Enter more data?(y/n)\n");
        scanf ("\n%c", &ch);
    }
    while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
    {
        tail->next = (list) malloc (sizeof (node));
        printf ("Enter the value for roll number:-\n");
        scanf ("%d", &(tail->next->roll_no));
        printf ("Enter name:-\n");
        scanf ("%s", tail->next->name);
        printf ("Enter marks:-\n");
        scanf ("%f", &(tail->next->marks));
        temp = tail;
        printf ("Enter more data?(y/n)\n");
        scanf ("\n%c", &ch);
    }
    while (temp->roll_no < tail->roll_no)
    {
        head = tail;
        tail = tail->next;
        temp->next = tail;
        head->next = temp;
    }
    show_list (head);
}

void
show_list (list start) 
{
    while (start != NULL)  
    {
        printf ("%d \t %s \t %f \n", start->roll_no, start->name,
        start->marks);
        start = start->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: I dont get link lists in sorted manner.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')` statement keeps adding data at the end of the list.

The `while (temp->roll_no < tail->roll_no)` statement condition will never be evaluated because, when you exit from the previous while loop, `temp = tail`. Think about your algorithm and try again.

Hints:

1. Segment your code
2. Make a function that creates a node `node *createNode()` and returns a pointer to it.
3. Make another function `void insertNode( node * start, node *newNode)`

Then, you can separate functions as

```
while( 1 ) {
      /* <
          code that checks if you want to continue
          and breaks out of the loop otherwise
       >*/

     insertNode(head, createNode())
}
```

and you are done.

You already have the `createNode()` pretty much done. Just work on the other one a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Your insertion mechanism is wrong. It always adds/overwrites at the 2nd  position.
Add the following two statements at the end of the 1st while loop to correct this:

tail=tail->next;

tail->next=NULL;

Then discard the 2nd while loop which is completely meaningless.

Then try to traverse and sort the list.

---

Otherwise, you can sort the list while adding the nodes. 
For this, replace the two while loops in your program by the following code:

```
while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
    {
        list T;
        temp = (list) malloc (sizeof (node));
        printf ("Enter the value for roll number:-\n");
        scanf ("%d", &(temp->roll_no));
        printf ("Enter name:-\n");
        scanf ("%s", temp->name);
        printf ("Enter marks:-\n");
        scanf ("%f", &(temp->marks));
        temp->next=NULL;
        if(temp->roll_no<head->roll_no)
        {
            temp->next=head;
            head=temp;
        }
        else{
        for(T=head;;T=T->next)
        {
            if(T->next==NULL)
            {
                T->next=temp;
                break;
            }
            if(temp->roll_no<T->next->roll_no)
            {
                temp->next=T->next;
                T->next=temp;
                break;
            }
        }
        }
        printf ("Enter more data?(y/n)\n");
        scanf ("\n%c", &ch);
    }
```